# Mongo range query became extremely slow on large collection

Tags: index, mongodb

I have a collection which has 50 million records in it.
After using wired Tiger its size became only 3 GB (2 GB data 700 MB index).
I have created index on this collection.
But when i do a range query on this collection it never came back.
Data sample of the collection is:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ebac553848234cbf9d0cbe"),
    "host" : "example.com",
    "articleId" : "46014571",
    "cat" : "City",
    "catIds" : [
            "-2128958273",
            "-2128932452",
            "36768500"
    ],
    "count" : NumberLong(1),
    "date" : NumberLong(1422124200)
 }
```

Index created on

```
"date_-1_host_1_catIds_1"
```

Here date is daily date in epoch. so for teh collection it has data for last 380 days.
I tried query

```
db.DayArticleCount.count({ "date" : { "$gt" : 1420050600,$lte:1420569000}});
```

It never came back on console. But these queries gave me result after a long waiting

```
db.DayArticleCount.count({ "date" : { "$gt" : 1420050600}});
db.DayArticleCount.count({ "date" : {$lte:1420569000}});
```

Here is the collStatus output

```
{
    "ns" : "History.DayArticleCount",
    "count" : 48362182,
    "size" : 7434,
    "avgObjSize" : 161,
    "storageSize" : 2074,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
            "metadata" : {
                    "formatVersion" : 1
            },
            "creationString" : "allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=0,checkpoint=(WiredTigerCheckpoint.62=(addr=\"01e307fa6d81e4bdfb90c1e307fa6e81e4383a545fe307fa6f81e4684413c1808080e481aaefc0e481ad9fc0\",order=62,time=1425383455,size=2175647744,write_gen=255328)),checkpoint_lsn=(169,8971392),checksum=uncompressed,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,id=14,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=1MB,memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=0,prefix_compression_min=4,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,value_format=u,version=(major=1,minor=1)",
            "type" : "file",
            "uri" : "statistics:table:collection-11-6901777088731378261",
            "LSM" : {
                    "bloom filters in the LSM tree" : 0,
                    "bloom filter false positives" : 0,
                    "bloom filter hits" : 0,
                    "bloom filter misses" : 0,
                    "bloom filter pages evicted from cache" : 0,
                    "bloom filter pages read into cache" : 0,
                    "total size of bloom filters" : 0,
                    "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle" : 0,
                    "chunks in the LSM tree" : 0,
                    "highest merge generation in the LSM tree" : 0,
                    "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist" : 0,
                    "sleep for LSM merge throttle" : 0
            },
            "block-manager" : {
                    "file allocation unit size" : 4096,
                    "blocks allocated" : 0,
                    "checkpoint size" : 2175647744,
                    "allocations requiring file extension" : 0,
                    "blocks freed" : 0,
                    "file magic number" : 120897,
                    "file major version number" : 1,
                    "minor version number" : 0,
                    "file bytes available for reuse" : 61440,
                    "file size in bytes" : 2175471616
            },
            "btree" : {
                    "column-store variable-size deleted values" : 0,
                    "column-store fixed-size leaf pages" : 0,
                    "column-store internal pages" : 0,
                    "column-store variable-size leaf pages" : 0,
                    "pages rewritten by compaction" : 0,
                    "number of key/value pairs" : 0,
                    "fixed-record size" : 0,
                    "maximum tree depth" : 6,
                    "maximum internal page key size" : 368,
                    "maximum internal page size" : 4096,
                    "maximum leaf page key size" : 3276,
                    "maximum leaf page size" : 32768,
                    "maximum leaf page value size" : 1048576,
                    "overflow pages" : 0,
                    "row-store internal pages" : 0,
                    "row-store leaf pages" : 0
            },
            "cache" : {
                    "bytes read into cache" : 6196206644,
                    "bytes written from cache" : 0,
                    "checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 0,
                    "unmodified pages evicted" : 28415,
                    "page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
                    "modified pages evicted" : 0,
                    "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 0,
                    "hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 0,
                    "internal pages evicted" : 0,
                    "pages split during eviction" : 0,
                    "in-memory page splits" : 0,
                    "overflow values cached in memory" : 0,
                    "pages read into cache" : 191244,
                    "overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
                    "pages written from cache" : 0
            },
            "compression" : {
                    "raw compression call failed, no additional data available" : 0,
                    "raw compression call failed, additional data available" : 0,
                    "raw compression call succeeded" : 0,
                    "compressed pages read" : 189766,
                    "compressed pages written" : 0,
                    "page written failed to compress" : 0,
                    "page written was too small to compress" : 0
            },
            "cursor" : {
                    "create calls" : 2,
                    "insert calls" : 0,
                    "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls" : 0,
                    "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted" : 0,
                    "next calls" : 0,
                    "prev calls" : 1,
                    "remove calls" : 0,
                    "cursor-remove key bytes removed" : 0,
                    "reset calls" : 64755604,
                    "search calls" : 64783848,
                    "search near calls" : 0,
                    "update calls" : 0,
                    "cursor-update value bytes updated" : 0
            },
            "reconciliation" : {
                    "dictionary matches" : 0,
                    "internal page multi-block writes" : 0,
                    "leaf page multi-block writes" : 0,
                    "maximum blocks required for a page" : 0,
                    "internal-page overflow keys" : 0,
                    "leaf-page overflow keys" : 0,
                    "overflow values written" : 0,
                    "pages deleted" : 0,
                    "page checksum matches" : 0,
                    "page reconciliation calls" : 0,
                    "page reconciliation calls for eviction" : 0,
                    "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression" : 0,
                    "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression" : 0
            },
            "session" : {
                    "object compaction" : 0,
                    "open cursor count" : 2
            },
            "transaction" : {
                    "update conflicts" : 0
            }
    },
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 721,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 418,
            "date_-1_host_1_catIds_1" : 303
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

Could you please suggest me how i can make these query faster.

Comment: Have you built the index after you changed the storage engine? My only idea at this moment is index fragmentation.

Comment: No i did not i just updated mongo from 2.6.4 to 3.0 with default mmap engine

Comment: Have you sorted this out? I have seen a post about a broken index after upgrade (older version though). Have you checked the query plan?